# Doctrine 2 - How to use discriminator column in where clause

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql, discriminator

I was used discriminator column in where clause like this:

```
//f = root entity
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');
$qb->add('where', 'f.format = \'image\' OR f.format = \'text\'');
```

I've got an error: "Message: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 73 near 'format = 'image'': Error: Class Entities\File\AbstractFile has no field or association named format"

How can i use discriminator column in where clause?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use `case when` and `INSTANCE OF` - see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690590/645042

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I think that you should use [INSTANCE OF](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#get-all-instances-of-a-specific-type)

Comment: More specifically $db->andWhere('f INSTANCE OF Entity\File\Image')

Comment: You can also use the keys of the discriminator map instead of the entity class name.

Comment: If you use a place holder (e.g., `'f INSTANCE OF :type'`) then you need to set the parameter as follows: `$query->setParameter('type', $em->getClassMetadata('Entity\File\Image'))`

Comment: `$db->andWhere($db->expr()->isInstanceOf('f', Entity\File\Image::class));`

Answer (score 15):

It would look in query builder like this:

```
$class = 'Entity\File\Image';

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');
$qb->where($qb->expr()->isInstanceOf('f', $class));
```

**Note**: that you will not be able to set the class as a parameter because it will be escaped.

Answer (score 4):

for PHP 5.50 and above:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('f')
        ->andWhere('f INSTANCE OF '.Image::class)
```

Answer (score 4):

As this latest doctrine version it is supported to query directly the discriminator value.

```
public function findOfType($discr)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
        $qb->where('e INSTANCE OF :discr');
        $qb->setParameter('discr', $discr);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

will have a result query with this clause:

```
WHERE e0_.discr IN ('discriminator_passed_to_function')
```

Answer (score 1):

This doctrine extension was very useful for me because I needed to access the parent class and `INSTANCE OF` doesn't works in that case.

https://gist.github.com/jasonhofer/8420677

For example: I have the following class structure:

**BaseClass**

**Class1** inherits from **BaseClass**  (discriminator = c1)

**Class2** inherits from **Class1**     (discriminator = c2)

**Class3** inherits from **Class1**     (discriminator = c3)

I want to select all entities from **Class1** but not from **Class2** or **Class3**

```
SELECT c FROM \Class1 c WHERE TYPE(c) = 'c1';
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('entity')
            ->andWhere('entity.field = :field')
            ->leftJoin('entity.entity2', 'entity2')
            ->andWhere('entity2 INSTANCE OF :type')
            ->setParameter('field', 'value')
            ->setParameter('type', $this->getEntityManager()->getClassMetadata(Entity2::class))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).