# Doctrine2 - How can I order by a discriminator column?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

How should I go about ordering by a discriminator column in a doctrine repository query?

I have a pretty straight forward setup, 
I have different types of payment details, 
it can either be Credit Card (CC) or Debit Order (DO).

So I've implemented a single table inheritance mapping strategy to achieve this, 
but the problem now comes in when I try to order by the discriminator column, since the discriminator column isn't present in the base class.

The repository function:

```
public function getPaymentDetails (ClientContactInterface $clientContact)
{
    $dql = 'SELECT pd
            from
            AccountingBundle:PaymentDetail pd
            JOIN ClientProductBundle:ClientProduct cp
            WITH cp.payment_detail_id = pd.id
            WHERE
            cp.payment_detail_id = pd.id
            and cp.client_contact_id = :client_contact_id
            GROUP BY pd.id
            ORDER BY pd.method_type'; // Since pd.method_type is the discriminator column, I cannot order by it. And I need to be able to.

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter('client_contact_id', $clientContact->getId());
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Base PaymentDetail entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AccountingBundle\Repository\PaymentDetailRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\Table(name="PaymentDetails")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="PaymentMethodType", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({ "DO" = "DOPaymentDetail", "CC" = "CCPaymentDetail"})
 */

class PaymentDetail implements PaymentDetailInterface
{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected  $id;

    /* etc... */
}
```

Debit Order PaymentDetail entity:

```
/**
 * AccountingBundle\Entity\DOPaymentDetail
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="PaymentDetails")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class DOPaymentDetail extends PaymentDetail implements DOPaymentDetailInterface
{

    /**
     * @var string $account_holder
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DOAccountHolder", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $account_holder;

    /* etc... */
}
```

Credit Card PaymentDetail entity:

```
/**
 * AccountingBundle\Entity\CCPaymentDetail
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="PaymentDetails")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CCPaymentDetail extends PaymentDetail implements CCPaymentDetailInterface
{

    /**
     *
     * @var string $card_holder
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CCCardHolder", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $card_holder;

    /* etc... */
}
```

When I try that, I get this error,

```
Error: Class AccountingBundle\Entity\PaymentDetail has no field or association named method_type")
```

Comment: look at your discriminator-column declaration `* @DiscriminatorColumn(name="PaymentMethodType"` and check what's the name of the generated column in your database ... I'm pretty sure the column-/field-name is `PaymentMethodType` and not `method_type`. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I can confirm this. But, the problem keeps coming in when I try to order by a column that technically doesn't exist in Doctrine's eyes, I  tried changing method_type to PaymentMethodType in the repo function, and I got... `("[Semantical Error] line 0, col 388 near 'PaymentMethodType': Error: 'PaymentMethodType' is not defined.")`

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701272/how-do-i-order-by-a-property-that-isnt-a-db-column-using-doctrine

Comment: I think it is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988636/doctrine-2-how-to-use-discriminator-column-in-where-clause/34156705#34156705

Comment: @Aistis - the answer you reference is about using a discriminator in a WHERE clause. This question is about using it in an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 4):

Even though TYPE is not implemented yet into the core of doctrine it's still possible to implement it as a custom user function.

Someone already did an amazing job and [implemented](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasonhofer/8420677/raw/9e30a47e4b7ce48be91da7c04359d304768ce4b6/doctrine-dql-type-function.php) it for us. Just in case the resource will be removed in the future, here is a slightly adjusted version for php7+:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class TypeFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $dqlAlias;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker): string
    {
        /** @var ClassMetadataInfo $class */
        $class = $sqlWalker->getQueryComponent($this->dqlAlias)['metadata'];
        $tableAlias = $sqlWalker->getSQLTableAlias($class->getTableName(), $this->dqlAlias);

        if (!isset($class->discriminatorColumn['name'])) {
            $message = 'TYPE() only supports entities with a discriminator column.';
            throw QueryException::semanticalError($message);
        }

        return $tableAlias . '.' . $class->discriminatorColumn['name'];
    }

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->dqlAlias = $parser->IdentificationVariable();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

Now you can order by the discriminator column by doing something like:

```
SELECT e, TYPE(e) AS HIDDEN my_type FROM Entity e ORDER BY my_type DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the simplest solution (so far) is to add another field to the base class and copy the discriminator column value.

The aforementioned `TYPE(q)` works only in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Can your try to use `TYPE()` or `INSTANCE OF`?

related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/JtCbwuN-37o

However, this topic doesn't say if it is implemented or not. At the time it was written someone said order by wouldn't work.

```
$dql = 'SELECT pd
        from
        AccountingBundle:PaymentDetail pd
        JOIN ClientProductBundle:ClientProduct cp
        WITH cp.payment_detail_id = pd.id
        WHERE
        cp.payment_detail_id = pd.id
        and cp.client_contact_id = :client_contact_id
        GROUP BY pd.id
        ORDER BY TYPE(pd)';
```

Comment: TYPE() is still not implemented AFAIK