# How do I order by a property that isn't a DB column using Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

When defining a relationship, there is a property on the related model (not a DB column), but I would like to sort by it (in the `@OrderBy` annotation).

I have a base model that is extended using [single table inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance). The property in question is basically an `order` property that is specified in each child class, but is not saved to the DB.

(I don't want to add an `order` column to the DB table, since the ordering depends purely on which child class the discriminator is mapped to. There is already a unique constraint so that each child class can be used no more than once in the relationship.)

Here's a really simplified version of my code...

#### Base entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="base")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="class_name", type="string")
 *
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *   "Base" = "Models\Base",
 *   "ChildA" = "Models\ChildB",
 *   "ChildB" = "Models\ChildA"
 * })
 **/
class Base 
{
    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
    protected $class_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Related", inversedBy="collection")
     **/
    protected $related;

    // this is just a plain ol' property (not in the DB)
    protected $order;

    public function getClassName()
    {
        return $this->class_name;
    }
}
```

#### Children:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="child_a")
 **/
class ChildA extends Base
{
    $order = 1;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="child_b")
 **/
class ChildB extends Base
{
    $order = 2;
}
```

#### Related entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="related")
 **/
class Related
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Base", mappedBy="related")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"order"="ASC"})
     **/
    protected $collection;

    public function getCollection()
    {
        $em = App::make('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface');

        // map each Base instance to the appropriate child class
        return $this->collection->map(function ($base) use ($em) {
            $class_name = $base->getClassName();
            return $em->find($class_name, $base->getId());
        });
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use the `order` property for ordering the `collection` relationship? (Ordering based on `class_name` using a `switch`-like construct would also be valid, but I haven't found any way to do that either, and it would be harder to maintain.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405866/doctrine2-how-can-i-order-by-a-discriminator-column

Answer (score 1):

The directive beginning with ORM is very much telling Doctrine you're doing referencing a property that has a relationship with a table field. You can't use ORM directives on fields that don't exist. [Doctrine annotations: OrderBy](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby)

You would have to implement this in a function, best in the model itself (within your getCollection() function), or if you're using a framework like Symfony place it in a function of the repository class for this entity. You'd have to use PHP sorting functions to do this. SQL/DQL won't work either because the property isn't related to a field in the table.