# Order a one-to-many relation based on object type in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

### **A little context:**

I have a website which people can do orders on. Each time someone adds an item to there order it add an OrderItem entity. To be able to define different properties I've made my OrderItem an abstract class which is extended by other objects like Subscription or Goodie.

### **The problem I'm having:**

Currently when I display the Order details I have a list of OrderItem that is displayed based on theOrderItem ID, meaning that depending on how the client add things to his cart I might have a list with:

- subscription
- goodie
- goodie
- subscription

### **What I would like to have:**

I would like to be able to order my one-to-many relation by object type as to have a list that looks like this:

- goodie
- goodie
- subscription
- subscription

### **What I have tried so far:**

[Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/ordered-associations.html) shows that you can order thanks to an annotation like `@OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})` so I tried to add `@OrderBy({"type" = "ASC"})` but the result is that "type" not being a recognized field Doctrine isn't able to order on it.

I have also tried to override the repository "createQueryBuilder" function but it has been a mess.

### **A little code to help out**

This is the `DiscriminatorMap` I have on my abstract OrderItem to link it to the other types and the reason I try to filter on "type" field.

```
 * @DiscriminatorMap(typeProperty="type", mapping={
 *     "subscription" = "App\Entity\Order\OrderItem\Subscription",
 *     "offer" = "App\Entity\Order\OrderItem\Offer",
 *     "goodie" = "App\Entity\Order\OrderItem\Goodie",
 *     "course" = "App\Entity\Order\OrderItem\Course",
 *     "option" = "App\Entity\Order\OrderItem\Option",
 *     "voucher" = "App\Entity\Order\OrderItem\Voucher",
 * })
```

Comment: Side note: that's ordering/sorting, not filtering.

Comment: _"...but the result is that "type" not being a recognized field..."_ - do you have a property called `type` in your class? Is it a column?

Comment: @El_Vanja: I've corrected my question based on your comment and added bit more description as to explain why I try to filter on the "type" field as it's the one used by the DiscriminatorMap

Comment: Also, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405866/doctrine2-how-can-i-order-by-a-discriminator-column but the last reaction is 3 years old, hopping for a little more recent data

Comment: Seems like trying to order on a discriminator column is a bit of a hassle. I'd say save yourself the trouble and order the collection with PHP.

Comment: @El_Vanja, it would be easier to do this at one and only place that's why I'm trying to to id in the Repository, it's also probably the most efficient way to obtain my ordered list.

Comment: Option 1: add the sorting inside the getter in the `Order` class. The overhead of sorting every time you use it is negligible. Option 2: create a custom repository method that fetches orders and do the sorting inside it, before you return the result.

Answer (score 0):

Until I find a better solution this is what has been setup in my project (thanks to @El_Vanja for the suggestion):

I've changed my Order object getter as to order the OrderItems before returning them. To do so I've used the following code:

```
public function getOrderItems(): Collection
{
    $orderedOrderItems = $this->orderItems->getIterator();

    $orderedOrderItems->uasort(
        function ($first, $second) {
            if (OrderItemHelper::getOrderBasedOnInstanceName(get_class($first)) === OrderItemHelper::getOrderBasedOnInstanceName(get_class($second))) {
                return 0;
            }
            return (OrderItemHelper::getOrderBasedOnInstanceName(get_class($first)) < OrderItemHelper::getOrderBasedOnInstanceName(get_class($second))) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    );

    return new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($orderedOrderItems));
}
```

The `OrderItemHelper::getOrderBasedOnInstanceName` is only a static method to be able to order the OrderItems in a specific order instead of ordering them by name or any other option.