# Symfony doctrine join related entities to discriminator columns

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine, discriminator

RoundMatch.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\MyBundle\Repository\RoundMatchRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"team_round_match" = "TeamRoundMatch", "player_round_match" = "PlayerRoundMatch"})
 * @ORM\Table("my_round_match")
 */
abstract class RoundMatch
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="match_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $matchDate;
```

How can I join related entities to discriminated entities?
I cannot get direct access to discriminated table columns to create joins.

I cannot get access to discriminated table columns to create joins. 
How can I join children entities to discriminator entities?

I created joins like this:

RoundMatchRepository.php

```
    public function getMatchesWithNoResultsSubmitted()
    {
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("rm");
            $qb->leftJoin("rm.round", "rnd" )
            ->leftJoin("rnd.group", "sg")
            ->leftJoin("sg.server", "ss")
            ->leftJoin("ss.stage", "ts")
            ->leftJoin("ts.tournament", "t")
            ->leftJoin("MyAppMyBundle:PlayerRoundMatch", "prm", "WITH", "rm.id = prm.id")
            ->leftJoin("prm.player1", "p1")
            ->leftJoin("prm.player2", "p2")
            ->leftJoin('p1.gameProfiles',"gp1")
            ->leftJoin('p2.gameProfiles',"gp2")
            ->leftJoin('p1.gameProfiles', 'gp1', "WITH", $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('t.game', 'gp1.game'),
                    $qb->expr()->eq('prm.player1', 'gp1.player')
                ))
            ->leftJoin('p1.gameProfiles', 'gp2', "WITH", $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('t.game', 'gp2.game'),
                    $qb->expr()->eq('prm.player2', 'gp2.player')
                ));
                return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I want to use result object in a twig and I cannot get joined entities in returned object because they are not joined via object relation.
I don't have object relation created because they are joined one to one via discriminator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 - How to use discriminator column in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988636/doctrine-2-how-to-use-discriminator-column-in-where-clause)

Comment: Looking more at your question. Personally, I don't think table inheritance is the answer for your requirements. A match should probably have its own record with the date. Then just simple relationships `match` <- `players`, `match` <- `team`, `player` <-> `team`.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved dynamic relationships using Single Table Inheritance. This will allow you to write DQL against the relation or against the discriminating class.

**You CANNOT "query" the discriminator using DQL.** You must INSTANCE OF the entity name, see [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988636/doctrine-2-how-to-use-discriminator-column-in-where-clause) as per @LBA's comment

In this resulting schema, `group_id` will mean a different relation depending on the discriminator.

Obviously, this has performance implications on the database, though.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string", length=255)
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(
 *   {"parents" = "Parents", "children" = "Child"}
 * )
 * @ORM\Table("people")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $group;
}

/*
 * @ORM\Table("parents")
 */
class Parent extends Person
{
    /**
     * Many parents have one group.
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ParentGroups", inversedBy="parents")
     * @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $group;
}

/*
 * @ORM\Table("children")
 */
class Child extends Person
{
    /**
     * Many children have one group.
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ChildGroups", inversedBy="children")
     * @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $group;
}

/*
 * @ORM\Table("parent_groups")
 */
class ParentGroups
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * One group has many parents.
     *
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Parent", mappedBy="group")
     */
    private $parents;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->parents = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/*
 * @ORM\Table("child_groups")
 */
class ChildGroups
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * One group has many parents.
     *
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="group")
     */
    private $children;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Effectively the extending tables can override the annotations (if any) of the parent.

It work's a dream and we have multiple uses of this on our monolith :)

Untested code, but it should give you an idea of how I achieved it. If you struggle from here I'll go and make sure it runs.